# No se visualiza la caja de herramientas para winform en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

al crear el form me debería mostrar todos los controladores o herramientas como input, label.
Y otros, pero no se que paso pero no me los muestra, eh buscado soluciones al restaurar el visual estudió a versiones de fabrica pero nada. Muestro imagen

---

[image: imagen de referencia]
imagen de referencia del error

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto visual studio te crea un formulario windows form vacio, para que dentro de el añadas el conjunto de controles que requieras añadir. Debes tener en cuenta que cada control cumple una funcion especifica

**En windows form**

- Label : Texto en formato solo lectura
- TextBox: Caja de texto para añadir texto
- GridView: Tablas
- ComboBox: Listas

**En Web Form**

- Label : Texto en formato solo lectura
- TextBox: Caja de texto para añadir texto
- GridView: Tablas
- DropDownList: Listas

Para poderlas ubicar, debes hacer uso del cuadro de herramientas el cual podras encontrar mediante la combinacion de teclas `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `X` o dirigiendote a la barra de navegacion de visual studio: Item Ver, y luego ubicar el item cuadro de herramientas.

Para hacer parte de tu formulario los controles a utilizar, los debes arrastrar del cuadro de herramientas y soltarlos en tu formulario.

**CASO 2.**

Por otro lado, valida que hayas instalado correctamente el visual studio, ya que podria deberse a que te hacen falta herramientas. Para ello lo que debes hacer es, ubicar el archivo de instalacion de visual estudio, se encuentra con el nombre Visual Studio installer, y chequear que esten instaladas las siguientes herramientas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de que no esten; añadelas, instala y reinicia el visual studio. Con ello ya se deberia quitar el error.

Comment: el detalle es que no muestra nada para arrastrar me dice que no hay utilizables en este grupo

Comment: Instalaste las dependencias al momento de realizar la instalacion de visual studio?

Comment: acabo de ajustar mi respuesta para que verifiques la instalación y realices el proceso.

Comment: La primera parte no viene a cuenta ya que la pregunta es por qué no le aparecen los controles.

Comment: creo que se ajusto la pregunta, sin embargo se deja la informacion a modo ilustración

Comment: ya lo intente segun yo instale lo que faltaba pero aun sigue asi :( help please

Comment: help my please, estoy estancado

Comment: Estoy igual que tú, ¿lo conseguiste solucionar?